# LibreOffice 5.0 - Fatal Error

Tags: upgrade, libreoffice

After the last upgrade from libreoffice I get a serious error that I'm not able to solve. I already tried reinstalling libreoffice with the debs but it dind't resolve it. The first couple of days however it worked fine but no I get the following error message any time I want to start an application:

" LibreOffice 5.0 - Fatal Error"

"The application cannot be started. User installation could not be completed"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These errors often arise due to bad profile configuration. Rename the profile folder using the following cmd:

```
 cd ~/.config && mv libreoffice libreoffice.old
```

New profile is generated automatically...

Source: [link](https://askubuntu.com/a/613997/438174)

Comment: deleted my interface customization but worked out. thanks!